# Python read file in through pipe and break on EOF

Tags: python, jpeg, pipe, eof

I currently have an application in which I am getting a long string of jpg's in as a string. I would like to break this string into individual files, but I can't find any clear way to recognize EOF's from within Python. I imagine this is a fairly common problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution for this. The string should only be about 20-30 jpgs long, so it's pretty small, but I'm not sure how to recognize EOF's as I go through the string.

I tried just splitting on `\0`, but it seems that this does not quite indicate EOF for these jpgs.

Comment: I'm confused, is the piece of data you're trying to break up a string, or a bunch of files?

Comment: Some more detail on how the input data is represented as well as how you utilize this application which gives you data within your code would help a lot.

Comment: [It is 3.5 inches of blank tape followed by ASCII character 13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)

Comment: @Andenthal It is a bunch of files represented as one string. Trying to break the string up into its constituent files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to restructure the sending of the files so that you receive them either one by one or with an unambiguous delimiter between each file in the byte stream.

If this is not possible, potentially, you can use the [APPO marker and ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure). So the marker would be either `0xFFE0[length]0x4A46585800` or `0xFFE0[length]0x4A46494600`.

Best case:

1. read stream until 0xFFE0 is found;
2. read two byte length (up to 65535×65535 pixels);
3. verify format by reading the next 5 bytes - break if not nul terminated JFIF or JFXX
4. read that length and deal with the payload;
5. loop back to 1

It would be better to deal with each file one by one however.